# Backend Validation with RESTAdapter always "The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**Configuration**

- Backend = Laravel 5.1, with Dingo API
- Frontend = Ember 1.13.6, Ember Data 1.13.7
- Adapter = Ember Data RESTAdapter

**The Problem**

I'm trying to handle backend validation errors on my first Ember application.  When errors are returned from the server, I get this error:

```
Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid
at new Error (native)
at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26266:21)
at Error.ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:69564:50)
at Error.ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$InvalidError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:69637:52)
at ajaxError (http://localhost:4200/assets/frontend.js:16:24)
at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.ajax.Ember.RSVP.Promise.hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:71327:31)
at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3350:30)
at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3462:7)
at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9518:14)
at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.options.send.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9920:8)
```

The response from the backend has a 422 Unprocessable Entity header, and the content is:

```
{
     "message":"Couldn't save client",
     "errors":{
          "name":["The name field is required."],
          "email":["The email field is required."]
      },
     "status_code":422
}
```

**Tried (and Failed) Solutions**

- [Ember data Rest adapter error handling not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712857/ember-data-rest-adapter-error-handling-not-working)
  Extending the RESTAdapter to override the ajaxError function, mine currently looks like this:

  ```
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
  var error = this._super(jqXHR);
  if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
      var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).errors;
      return new DS.InvalidError(jsonErrors);
  } else {
      return error;
  }
  }
  ```
- Adding a catch statement to the save method, my save action is currently:

  ```
   save() {
      var self = this;

      function transitionToPost(post) {
          self.transitionToRoute('clients.show', post);
      }

      function failure(reason) {
          // handle the error
          console.log(reason);
          return false;
      }

      this.get('model').save().then(transitionToPost, failure).catch(failure);
  }
  ```
- Testing out the ActiveModelAdapter - not sure what I was expecting to acheive with this one, but I got desperate; the result was still the same.
- Ember Docs (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_promises)
  As you can see in my controller code above, I actually used this as a base

Please can you have a look and advise?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: OK, so I uninstalled ember data and reinstalled it and then everything started working properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError(jqXHR) {
    var error, errors, jsonErrors, response;
    error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
      response = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
      errors = {};
      if (response.errors != null) {
        jsonErrors = response.errors;
        Ember.keys(jsonErrors).forEach(function(key) {
          return errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key];
        });
      }
      return new DS.InvalidError(errors);
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  }
});
```

Combined with custom `ServerErrorsMixin` for models:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  isntValid: Ember.computed.not('isValid').readOnly(),

  adapterDidInvalidate(errors) {
    let recordErrors = this.get('errors'),
        hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

    for (let key in errors) {
      if (!hasProp.call(errors, key)) {
        continue;
      }

      let propertyErrors = errors[key];

      if(key === 'duplicate') {
        if(!Ember.isArray(propertyErrors)) {
          recordErrors
          .get('messages')
          .pushObject(propertyErrors);
        } else {
          Ember.debug('It shouldnt be an array.');
        }
      } else {
        for (let e of propertyErrors) {
          recordErrors
          .get(key)
          .pushObject(e);
        }
      }
    }

    this._saveWasRejected();
  }
});
```

Works fine in Ember Data `1.0.0-beta.18`. If you try this remember to extend from `ServerErrorsMixin` in model:

```
import ServerErrorsMixin from '../mixins/server-errors';

export default DS.Model.extend(ServerErrorsMixin, {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: I've just tried this exactly as you've described, but I'm still getting the same error.  It's definitely hitting the ajaxError method, I've console logged the errors at that point, but it never hits the "adapterDidInvalidate" in the mixin, which I've now used in my model.